# finding the next element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have something like this:

```
<div class='span6'>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
       <div class='span2 search'>
          <img src='img.png'/> <!-- when clicked -->
       </div>
       <div class='span10'>
          <div class='name-info' id="test">  <!-- get this id -->
            <h4 class="name"><?php echo $name;?></h4>
            <div class='address'>
              <?php echo $location;?>
           </div>
         </div> <!-- end name-info -->
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end name-block -->
</div>
<div class='span6'>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
       <div class='span2 search'>
          <img src='img.png'/>  <!-- when clicked -->
       </div>
       <div class='span10'>
          <div class='name-info' id="test">  <!-- get this id -->
            <h4 class="name"><?php echo $name;?></h4>
            <div class='address'>
              <?php echo $location;?>
           </div>
         </div> <!-- end name-info -->
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end name-block -->
</div>

$('.search img').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).next('.name-info').attr("id"));
});
```

I have two exact divs and I'm trying to click on an img, and when I click on the image, it should be able to get the id of the class `name-info`, which way do I do this? I tried a few functions but not familiar with all jQuery functions. Need help please?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any `.searchimg` elements, and you have overlapping id attributes

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry, its supposed to be a space between that, as you can see I've noted what i need to click and show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
$('.search img').on('click',function(e){
    alert($(this).parent().next().find('.name-info').attr('id'))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZgT7u/)

Since you are clicking the `img` element, you need to get the `next slibling` of the parent, then find the element with class `name-info`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".span2 img").on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this).parent().next().find('.name-info').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think $('.searchimg') should be $('.search img') with what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.searchimg').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).parent().next().children('.name-info').attr("id"));
});
```